# join tables by datetime stamp (stripping the seconds)

Tags: datetime, join, multiple-tables, mysql-5.5

I have two tables, both have datetime stamps in them. Each table has a new entry every 60 seconds (approx) I would like to match up the times excluding the seconds but can't figure out how to strip off the seconds.

`SELECT t1.ts, t2.ts
FROM t1
JOIN t2
ON FORMAT([t1.ts], 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm') = FORMAT([t2.ts], 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm')`

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  And, why doesn't your query work?

Comment: if you are on sql 2012+ what you wrote should work

Comment: FYI: You're selecting the versions that still have the seconds.  Perhaps it's misleading you?

Comment: Do you really want to join records that are within 60 seconds of each other? What if one records is at 1 min 45 seconds and the other is at 2 min 30 seconds they are only 45 seconds apart but wouldn't match if you just strip the seconds off

Comment: The "ts" fields look like this `2016-07-07 16:51:56`
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[t1.ts], 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm') = FORMAT([t2.ts], 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm') LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

Comment: Not too worried about the time not syncing up. The output is being used for a google chart and displays a minimum of 6 hours @ one hour intervals. If it skips a minute you probably wouldn't even notice. That and the two loggers drive maybe 1-2 seconds a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use integer division to match on minutes:

```
SELECT t1.ts, t2.ts
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON TO_SECONDS(t1.ts) DIV 60 = TO_SECONDS(t2.ts) DIV 60
```

[`TO_SECONDS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds) returns the number of seconds since year zero and [`DIV`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) discards the fractional part of the division, so the expression `TO_SECONDS(...) DIV 60` is effectively the number of whole minutes since year zero.